# how to use regular expression in mongomodel for rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Hello I use rails3+mongodb+mongomodel but I have problem

How to use regular expression search data in mongodb 
this code in controller

```
@article = Article.where('title'=>'/Brown/i')
```

but it can not found data in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mongoid you pass a regexp as is, without quotes. Probably should work similarly for mongomodel:

```
Article.where('title'=>/Brown/i)
```